# Form Error Handleing in include file PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, echo

i am new in php and i am programming a simple form file that is included in a php webpage. 
this is the main page

makepedido.php

```
<!--Informacion Personal-->
<?php include 'personalinformation.php'; ?>
```

personalinformation.php

```
<form action="scripts.php" method="post" name="personalinfo" class="form"       id="personalinfo">
<table width="100%" class="tableform">
<tr>
<td>Nombre</td>
<td><input name="Nombre" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Apellido</td>
<td><input name="Apellido" type="text" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Direccion 1</td>
<td><input name="Direccion1" type="text" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Direccion 2</td>
<td><input name="Direccion2" type="text" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ciudad</td>
<td><input name="Ciudad" type="text" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Pais</td>
<td><input name="Pais" type="text" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Numero de Telefono</td>
<td><input name="NumerodeTelefono" type="text" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Correo Electronico</td>
<td><input name="CorreoElectronico" type="text" required></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<input value="Crear Pedido" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> <br />

</form>
```

scripts.php

```
<?php

$email = $_POST["CorreoElectronico"];

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
  echo "Correo invalido intente de nuevo";
  die;
}

?>
```

now i just want to know how to put in personalinformation.php the error returned by scripts.php, when i click the submit button, the browser goes to script.php and show the error msg.

i want it to stay in makepedido.php and show the error msg from the personalinformation.php form returned by scripts.php

Comment: You're either going to need to put your entire code inside the same file and using `action=""` or use Ajax/JS to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax to submit the form and get the error to the same page, like this:

```
$("#formID").submit(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/scripts.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: i tried this javascript code everywhere and it doesnt handle the error that the scripts.php echoes. it keeps sending me to scripts.php echoing the error.